# How to run multiple webpack task before build in visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio, webpack, package.json, task-runner-explorer

I have multiple webpack file with different 'purpose' and before and I need to run different webpack tasks, for example:

```
package.json:
"scripts": {
  "webpack-dll": "set NODE_ENV=dll && webpack",
  "webpack-admin": "set NODE_ENV=admin && webpack",
  "webpack-dev": "set NODE_ENV=dev && webpack"
}
```

Before build I want to run 'dll' 'admin' and 'dev' task. But I can't bind more than one task to before build section.

[image]

Is there any solution to solve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create another entry in the scripts section in package.json and call that.

```
"scripts": {
  "webpack-dll": "set NODE_ENV=dll && webpack",
  "webpack-admin": "set NODE_ENV=admin && webpack",
  "webpack-dev": "set NODE_ENV=dev && webpack",
  "before-build: "npm run webpack-dll && npm run webpack-admin && npm run webpack-dev"
}
```

Another option is to add the [npm-run-all](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-run-all) package. Then you can run the tasks in parallell like this:

```
"scripts": {
  "webpack-dll": "set NODE_ENV=dll && webpack",
  "webpack-admin": "set NODE_ENV=admin && webpack",
  "webpack-dev": "set NODE_ENV=dev && webpack",
  "before-build: "run-p webpack-dll && npm run webpack-admin && npm run webpack-dev"
}
```